# is it possible to send discount code from cart page to checkout page in shopify?

Tags: jquery, laravel, shopify

How we can send discount code from cart page to checkout page? I am trying to add discount code on cart page in hidden field and want to use it on checkout page automatically. I also don't want to enter discount code on checkout page manually.

I have discount code on cart page and I am trying to put it into hidden filed with the help of javascript. following is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",        
    url: url,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    success: function(data) {
    var dcv = data.discountCode;
    console.log(dcv);
    document.getElementById("quantityDiscount").value = 'dcv';
   }
});
```

from above Ajax call, I received discount code in my dcv variable and put it on input field having #quantityDiscount as id. following is my input filed where I am trying to save this discount code.

```
<input  id="quantityDiscount" class="js-form-discount" type="hidden" name="discount" value="" >
```

Please look at this issue and help me to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not put it in localstorage more about localstorage https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: there is more then one way to achieve that you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for sending it to checkout page

```js
localStorage.setItem("discount", dcv);
// Retrieve
localStorage.getItem("discount"); 

console.log(localStorage.getItem("discount"))   // your discount value
```

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("discount", dcv);
// Retrieve
sessionStorage.getItem("discount"); 

console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("discount"))   // your discount value
```

- The localStorage and sessionStorage properties allow to save key/value pairs in a web browser.
- The sessionStorage object stores data for only one session (the data is deleted when the browser tab is closed).

Comment: @VikasGhai try local storage or session storage of javascrpit

Comment: I have used local storage but here is another problem with local storage, it show previous value even I got new value in my console.

Comment: update value of discount in localstorage when discount is updated or you can use sessionStorage which store values util  tab is opened

Comment: Okay let me try with this.

Comment: @VikasGhai if its works then accept this answer so it will not populate in unanswered questions

Comment: sure @Akash, but let me try with this, I am working on this. once it complete  I will accept your answer.

Comment: it works but I have an another thing to do, do you know how we can add more than one discount code on shopify checkout page automatically?

Comment: in that case you can use different keys discount1 discount2 or store as array

Comment: Okay let me try with this too.